# Partition matrix to minimize variance of parts

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix of real numbers and I would like to find a partition of this matrix such that the both the number of parts and the variance of the numbers in each part are minimized. Intuitively, I want as few parts as possible, but I also want all the numbers within any given part to be close together.

More formally, I suppose for the latter I would find for each part the variance of the numbers in that part, and then take the average of those variances over all the parts. This would be part of the "score" for a given solution, the other part of the score would be, for instance, the total number of elements in the matrix minus the number of parts in the partition, so that fewer parts would lead to this part of the score being higher. The final score for the solution would be a weighted average of the two parts, and the best solution is the one with the highest score.

Obviously a lot of this is heuristic: I need to decide how to balance the number of parts versus the variances. But I'm stuck for even a general approach to the problem.

For instance, given the following simple matrix:

```
10, 11, 12, 20, 21
 8, 13,  9, 22, 23
25, 23, 24, 26, 27
```

It would be a reasonable solution to partition into the following submatrices:

```
10, 11, 12    |   20, 21
 8, 13,  9    |   22, 23
--------------+----------
25, 23, 24    |   26, 27
```

Partitioning is only allowed by slicing vertically and horizontally.

Note that I don't need *the* optimal solution, I just need an approach to get a "good" solution. Also, these matrices are several hundred by several hundred, so brute forcing it is probably not a reasonable solution, unless someone can propose a good way to pare down the search space.

Comment: Your objective is not very well defined. What does it mean to minimize "the variance of the numbers in each part"? Do you mean to minimize the sum of the variances over all parts? Something else? Also, how can you minimize _both_ the number of parts and the variance in each part?

Comment: You're right, of course. I've edited the question to try to clarify a little better. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be better off by starting with a simpler problem. Let's call this

- Problem A: given a fixed number of vertical and/or horizontal partitions, where should they go to minimize the sum of variances (or perhaps some other measure of variation, such as the sum of ranges within each block).

I'd suggest using a dynamic programming formulation for problem A.

Once you have that under control, then you can deal with

- Problem B: find the best trade-off between variation and the number of vertical and horizontal partitions.

Obviously, you can reduce the variance to 0 by putting each element into its own block. In general, problem B requires you to solve problem A for each choice of vertical and horizontal partition counts that is considered.

To use a dynamic programming approach for problem B, you would have to formulate an objective function that encapsulates the trade-off you seek. I'm not sure how feasible this is, so I'd suggest looking for different approaches.

As it stands, problem B is a 2D problem. You might find some success looking at 2D clustering algorithms. An alternative might be possible if it can be reformulated as a 1D problem: trading off variation with the number of blocks (instead of the number of vertical and horizontal partition count). Then you could use something like the [Jenks natural breaks classification method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization) to decide where to draw the line(s).

Anyway, this answer clearly doesn't give you a working algorithm. But I hope that it does at least provide an approach (which is all you asked for :)).

Comment: Given the ability to do choose e.g. best horizontal lines via DP on an array which is already split by one or more vertical lines you could then iterate the process in an attempt to hill-climb - find best horizontal then best vertical then best horizontal and so on.

Comment: @mcdowella - That seems like it would be a good strategy. I don't know if there are matrices where it would get stuck in a local minimum. A theoretical result showing that hill-climbing would always work, or, contrariwise, one that characterized what matrices might give a problem, would be very useful. I don't know of any such results, though.

Comment: I suspect that a matrix of all zeros except for the very top left and bottom right cells will have two local optima, each with just a single non-zero cell walled off from the rest. By adjusting the values slightly you may be able to get a local optimum not a global optimum. It looks like the sort of problem where you can find multiple local optima by finding symmetries that turn one into the other.